# How to correctly write my t-shirt text?

Tags: orthography

I work in a school with different institutes (one for math, one for computer science, etc.).

I like to print some t-shirts for an event. Our institute is called "IsMd", so i like to print t-shirts with this text:

```
  IsMd
   #1
institute
```

But I am not even sure if "#1" can be written in this way? Do people understand this? Then my second question is if I have to write "institute" or "Institute"?

Thank you very much

Comment: Surely you could do a little research to see how many other logo-bearing Items out there use ‘#1’

Comment: Why bother with the word *Institute*?

Comment: It's a friggin' T-shirt.  You can put anything you want on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

People definitely understand "#1" as meaning the top ranked or best of something.

"Institute" technically probably shouldn't be capitalized unless it's a proper name, but on a t-shirt I'd suggest doing whatever you think looks nicest, as people are not likely to care about the technicality on a shirt.

Comment: People also understand #1 (as opposed to #6 or #17 say) as being a use of nominal data. This question (and this answer) is unsuitable on a site aimed at linguists.